# VBA optional parameters

Tags: vba, parameters, option-type

```
Private Sub a()
   b 1,
End Sub

Private Sub b(p1 As Variant, Optional p2 As Variant)
   Stop
End Sub
```

I am Using VBA in Access.  I want to have a Procedure with 2 parameters - the last 1 being optional.
Why won't Private Sub a() compile.

How do I run a() with a call to b() and pass no parameter as the second argument?

Comment: just `b 1` without comma

Comment: just b 1 works but the problem is that assume I wish to have three parameters with the last 2 be optional it always returns a compile error if the 3rd (last) parameter is missing

Comment: use named parameters: `b p1:=1`

Comment: Yes OK Thank You

Private Sub a()
b p1:=1, p2:=1
End Sub

Private Sub b(p1 As Variant, Optional p2 As Variant, Optional p3 As Variant)
   Stop
End Sub

p3 is not mentioned anywhere in Sub a() and so it is missing.
Rather than b 1,1,

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing `,` breaks the syntax rules, omit it:

```
b 1
```

(Or provide a placeholder `b 1, p2:`)

Comment: Could you please show the sub a() and sub b() code with the last parameter as missing?  Thank You